# converting lots of string lists to floats

Tags: python-3.x, list, type-conversion

I found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681774/convert-strings-in-list-to-float) how to convert a list of strings to floats:

```
list_of_floats = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), list_of_string_floats))
```

I actually have 12 lists to convert:

```
U_mag = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), U_mag))
B_mag = list(.........................................B_mag))
```

etc.

Some of the lists contain items like `'-999.000'`, which I want to convert to a float, while others have items like `'act'` or `'QSO'`, which will be left as strings. Of course, I could write the same line as above 12 times!

I've tried

```
for item in (U_mag, B_mag, V_mag, R_mag, K_mag, W1_mag,
          W2_mag, W3_mag, W4_mag, L_UV, Q, flag_uv):
    try:
        item = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), item))
    except:
        pass
```

This doesn't throw up any errors, but it doesn't change the lists as expected. Surely there's a better way than writing out the same code 12 times.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning the list with a new one you lose the reference to the original list you want to replace.

So instead of:

```
item = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), item))
```

You should assign the new list to a temporary variable, and if it doesn't raise an exception, clear the original list and extend it with the temporary list, so not to lose the original reference:

```
temp = list(map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), item))
item.clear()
item.extend(temp)
```